# Update matrix in-place in Clojure

Tags: matrix, clojure

Suppose I have a Clojure matrix `A` as such (formatted for clarity)

```
[[1 4 3]
 [1 7 3]
 [1 8 3]]
```

Now suppose I want to update the first column in place, by e.g. multiplying it by a factor of two, so that the new matrix becomes

```
[[2 4 3]
 [2 2 3]
 [2 8 3]]
```

How would one do this in clojure? I have tried things like `assoc` and stuff like

`(join-along 1 (* (slice A 1 0) 2) (select A [0 1 2] [2 3]))`

Naturally that did not work. It would be great if there was something like `assoc` for matrices e.g.

```
(massoc A [rows] [columns] replacement-vector)
```

or something simple like `numpy` in Python:

```
A[:,0]*2 = [[2 4 3]
            [2 2 3]
            [2 8 3]]
```

Thanks

Comment: That's more similar to `numpy` syntax in Python, not MATLAB.  I'm just nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [clojure.core/matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) and see if it supports operations like this.

Here is something that may be what you're looking for. It should be trivial to change this to `assoc` a new value rather than updating after applying a function.

```
(defn mupdate-in
  "Update all `coll' rows at `column' with `f'"
  [coll column f & args]
  (reduce #(apply update-in %1 [%2 column] f args)
          coll
          (range (count coll))))
```

An example:

```
(def m [[1 4 3]
        [1 7 3]
        [1 8 3]])

(mupdate-in m 0 * 2)
;; [[2 4 3]
;;  [2 7 3]
;;  [2 8 3]]

(mupdate-in m 2 + 10)
;; [[1 4 13]
;;  [1 7 13]
;;  [1 8 13]]
```