# In place matrix operations in Clojure

Tags: matrix, clojure

I asked a related question before:

[Update matrix in-place in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418058/update-matrix-in-place-in-clojure)

And unfortunately, being new to Clojure, I am even more confused now.

Essentially what I would like to do, in Python syntax, is simply, with matrix `A`:

```
[[1 4 3]
 [1 7 3]
 [1 8 3]]
```

take the determinant of `A`, call it `D`, and then do

```
A[:,0] = A[:,0]*(D /abs(D))
```

upon which I would like to do

```
A = A*(D**(-1./A.shape[0]))
```

But even while perusing the functionality of `core.matrix` it is proving very difficult to figure out how something quite as simple is done in Clojure, even with the help of the previous question.

I have got this far [in clojure syntax]:

```
(join-along 1 (* (slice A 1 0) (/ (det A) (abs (det A)))) (select A [0 1 2] [1 2]))
```

but then then how to update in-place, without storing in variable? Currently getting error message:

```
Unidentified exception when trying to call procedure join-along with arguments (1 [1.0 4.0 7.0] #<NDWrapper [[2 3] [5 6] [8 9]]>)
```

Yet this works:

```
>(def t1 [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]])
>(def t2 [[9] [9] [9]])
>(join-along 1 t2 t1)
[[9 1 1] [9 2 2] [9 3 3]]
```

If that could be figured out then it should simply be an issue of doing:

```
(* "A-updated-matrix" (pow (det A) (/ -1 (dimension-count A 0)))
```

Also I can imagine that the above is probably not the most efficient way of performing these matrix operations.

**UPDATE:**

So it appears to be a problem with the clojure accesses matrices, and outputting column vectors as row vectors.

E.g.

```
>(def a [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
>(def t2 (get-column a 0)) ; Gets first column 
>(join-along 1 t2 a)
Unidentified exception when trying to call procedure join-along with   arguments (1 [1 4 7] [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
```

However if we do

```
>(def i [[2] [3] [4]])
>(join-along 1 i a)
[[2 1 2 3] [3 4 5 6] [4 7 8 9]]
```

it works fine.

Comment: Regardless of the other details, in place update of vectors isn't a thing without ugly and unsafe hacks. If you want actual in-place update, use a mutable type, like arrays. Sadly I can't tell you whether and how core.matrix handles arrays.

Comment: @noisesmith is right, Astrid.   core.matrix allows you to choose different underlying implementations.  Currently the most complete are `persistent-vector`, i.e. regular Clojure vectors of vectors, which are immutable; `ndarray`, which is a pure Clojure implementation that supports mutable matrices; and `vectorz`, which is a Java implementation that also supports mutable matrices.  You can select an implementation default with, for example, `(set-current-implementation :vectorz)`, or add the `:vectorz` or `:ndarray` keyword when you create a matrix, e.g. with `(matrix :ndarray [[1 2][3 4]])`.

Comment: If you're trying to write a particular element in a matrix, `mset!` is probably the operator you need.  (I don't know Python matrix syntax, so I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you explain what you want to do in words, or explain the syntax?)

Comment: Concerning the last two code examples:  In core.matrix, `[[1 2 3]]` represents a row vector, `[[1][2][3]]` represents a column vector, and `[1 2 3]` is a vector that can be interpreted as a row or column vector depending on context ([see this page](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/wiki/Vectors-vs.-matrices)).  `join-along` apparently expects an explicit row or column vector representation.